# R code for (a^2 + b^2 = c^2) < 1000 (Pythagoras)

Tags: r

Pythagoras triples are three positive integers a, b and c with a^2 + b^2 = c^2. 
need to use R to list all possible triples with a b and c less than 1000 and a < b < c.
Cannot use control flow constructs (if, for, while and repeat)
There should be 881 triples.
Thank you :)

```
vals <- expand.grid(x=seq(1000), y=seq(1000))
subset(vals, x^2 + y^2.....)
```

not sure where to go from here

Comment: why are people downvoting?  this is an amazing question

Comment: @AnthonyDamico: It looks a lot like a "Solve my homework problem for me" question, with no indication of effort on the poster's part.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Comment: completely lost! so far i have used the expand.grid function and subseted the values but i can't get it to fit together

Comment: @MarkDickinson that may be true.. but it's still and awesome question (and pretty hard at that)   jonrsharpe what? haha yes it is!  that's the whole point.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code you have tried.

Comment: Subset the expand.grid data.frame after adding a column that is the sum of the squares. Sum needs to be < 1000^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create a data.frame with all possible combos
vals <- expand.grid( x = 1:1000 , y = 1:1000 )

# calculate the z for each of these
vals$z <- sqrt( vals$x^2 + vals$y^2 )

# subset all possible combinations where z is an integer and x, y, z are <= 1000 and x < y and y < z
actuals <- subset( vals , z == round( z ) & ( x <= 1000 ) & ( y <= 1000 ) & ( z <= 1000 ) & ( x < y ) & ( y < z ) )

# answer
nrow( actuals )

# look at the first six records
head( actuals )

# plot x and y
plot( actuals$x , actuals$y )
```

Comment: Why does x need to be less than y. Can't they be '=='. And wouldn't it be sufficient to require that z be < 1000?

Comment: Try plotting x and y.

Comment: damn that is beautiful.  i love this question.  and math too haha

Comment: So, what are those 4 lines?

Comment: man, this is awesome.  the first one is `subset( actuals , y == x * 4/3 )` the second one is `subset( actuals , y == x * 8/6 )` and so on..  those ratios easily viewed with `head( actuals )`

Comment: I think y == x * 8/6 is the same line as y == x * 4/3. I eventually figured out the ratios for three of the lines that I was seeing, too, although there was one of the lines that I didn't find the base ratio for even in `head(actuals,50)`. Try y= x*12/5 and y=x*15/8. I'm also forming the theory that all the points would form some line or another but that the distance between the points may be too large to see on this plot.

Comment: right duh. sorry the second line is 12/5.  :)  quick way to see the first six lines: `head( sort( table( actuals$y / actuals$x ) , decreasing = TRUE ) )`